# Dynamic versions (using +) of dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, versions

I am using `compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.8+'` in my project.
I want to know that is the latest version of this dependency is picked when the release apk is created or every time when the user opens the app (downloaded from playstore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new version downloads when You create a new build. There is nothing changes in it before You create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You should **avoid the use** of the `+` in your dependencies.

In this way you **will not be able to replicate your build** in the future because you can't know the versions used in your app.

Dynamic versions add nondeterminism to your build and can introduce unexpected behavior changes to your app.

To check *Newer Library Versions Available* you can use a lint check:

- Go to Settings > Editor > Inspections > "Newer Library Versions Available"
- Enable the **Newer Library Versions Available** inspection
- Go to Analyze > "Run Inspection By Name" and search for **Newer Library Versions Available**
  [image]
- You will launch a link check

[image]

Comment: "You should avoid the use of the + in your dependencies." You can always lock the versions in the gradle.lockfile

Answer (score 1):

`+` here known as dynamic dependencies.

Simply + will use the latest or updated dependency but Using dynamic dependencies (for example, `com.localytics.android:library:3.8+`) can cause unexpected version updates and regression incompatibilities as suggested by google docs

Pros

- Stay updated
- Manually updating dependencies can be tedious

Cons

- Can break your current code flow due to changes in lib code
- Usually there can be some bug found in the new releases so be ready to face unexpected behavior or crash

Conclusion : As advised by google always specify the library version [check under  Adding Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)